# CSS: Reset INPUT Element to Original Width

Tags: html, css, browser, cross-browser

I don't think this is possible but I am going to ask it nonetheless, lets say I have the following HTML:

```
<div style="width: 500px;">
    <input class="full" />
</div>
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
input {
    width: 100%;
}

.full {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 2%;
    width: 96%
}
```

In this case my input element will have a width of 480px, this works fine for most of my needs but in some specific cases it doesn't, for instance:

```
<div style="width: 500px;">
    <input name="day" size="2" />
    <input name="month" size="2" />
    <input name="year" size="4" />
</div>
```

This will make the browser render each input with a width of 500px ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kQDpY/))...

Is there anyway to force the browser to rollback to the default style?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set `width:auto` to those inputs. This works with or without setting the `size` attribute (respects size if you have set it).

http://jsfiddle.net/Madmartigan/kQDpY/3/

BTW, float will automatically set the display type to block, your inline declaration for the div isn't doing anything so you don't need it.

Answer (score 3):

Just override it with an `!important` selector:

```
input {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

And a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kQDpY/4/

Comment: +1, Thanks. Is there any specific reason why you are using the `!important` attribute?

Comment: Just to be safe, as it overrides all other `width` attributes in effect for that element.

Answer (score 1):

### width: auto;

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kQDpY/5/) what you're after?

Basically I've set `width:auto;` to all inputs that define `size` attribute. Maybe this isn't the correct attribute but it shows how you can distinguish inputs between each other.

But basically you haven't told us what you'd like with these three inputs. Would you want them to occupy the whole width but should be 2:2:4 in size or is it just auto with as it seems we all did...

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my reply, what I need is exactly what you have posted, +1! I would mark your answer as accepted but @Madmartigan got to it a bit earlier. I have one doubt about your example though: is the `input[size]` declaration cross-browser compatible? I am under the impression that it doesn't work on some IE versions.

Comment: @Alix: Which versions do you require to support?

Comment: I would be happy if it worked on IE >= 6, but I guess 7 is OK too.

Comment: @Alix: According to http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html IE7 is fine with this CSS selector. IE6 unfortunately not. But you said that IE7 would be fine.